# Python - In a text file, strip a line containing a number greater than a certain value

Tags: python, if-statement, integer, strip

I have the following code:

```
with open(rawfile) as f, open(outfile,'w') as f2:
    for x in f:
      if (':') not in x and ('Station') not in x and('--')not in x and('hPa') not in x:
          f2.write(x.strip()+'\n')
```

The "...if ___ not in x..." lines identify a line containing that string and removes the line while keeping the rest of the text in the same format. I would like to do this same thing, but remove any line containing a number greater than 10000.

Comment: You need to parse the line in some fashion compatible with the input format (which you've failed to provide), convert the desired number to `int`, and check that value.  Where are you stuck?  Please provide your problem code, along with a few representative input lines.

Comment: Also, please edit your question: you're asking to delete the lines, simply not writing them to the new file.  `strip` is a specific operation with regard to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to this by incorporating Regex (since what you have is a string). For that, you could do something like

```
import re    

re.findall(r'\d{5,}', str)
```

This will identify numbers with 5 or more digits. Include this in some sort of if clause to remove the numbers you desire gone.

If you're wanting to identify the whole line including a 5 digit or more number, you can use

```
re.findall(r'^.+(\d{5,}).+$', str)
```

Comment: This is only writing lines with 5 values (instead of deleting them), but that is something I can work on and gives me a great starting place!

Comment: Yes, it will only find them. But you can include it in whatever if clause fits for you to make it work. Just trying to give you the bones. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use [regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and grouping:

```
match = re.match(r'regexpToIdentyMyNumber(\d+)', x)
my_number = float(match.group(1)))
if my_number > 10000:
    continue # do my thing
```

Basically you need to define a pattern that identifies your number and then use the parentheses to declare and save the number (the `\d+`) as a group, which can then be used to do further calculations.